# method.Invoke() doesn't seem to be working C#

Tags: c#, dll, invoke

I am making a project in c# using a .dll. To let the .dll output to a richtextbox (which I'm using as console) I've made a listener to check if a variable on the .dll has changed, and if so, output that variable in the richtextbox. That part works. However, the invoke method doesn't work (I think) because the variable isn't changing when I use the invoke. This is my code in the .exe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Dark_Magic_Origins
{
    public partial class game : Form
    {
        static string listenerPath;
        static string prevOutput = String.Empty;
        static Assembly DLL;
        static MethodInfo method;
        static Type theType;
        static object c;

        public game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(closingThaForm);

            if (WhatIsNext.whatsNext.Equals("new"))
            {
                timer.Interval = 500;
                timer.Enabled = true;

                loadDLL(Application.StartupPath + @"\bin\story\Chapter 1.dll", "Chapter_1.Class1", "guideLine");

                method.Invoke(c, new object[0]);
            }
        }

        private void closingThaForm(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SharedVars.closeProgram == true)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInput.Text))
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            }
            else if (SharedVars.enableSpeech == true)
            {
                console.Text += Environment.NewLine + "<" + SharedVars.name + "> " + txtInput.Text;
                txtInput.Text = String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            }
        }

        private void loadDLL(string path, string namespaceDotClass, string Method)
        {
            DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

            theType = DLL.GetType(namespaceDotClass);
            c = Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
            method = theType.GetMethod(Method);
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IList<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>(theType.GetFields());

            object fValue = new Object();
            foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
            {
                if (f.Name.Equals("output"))
                {
                    fValue = f.GetValue(c);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!prevOutput.Equals(fValue.ToString()))
            {
                console.Text += Environment.NewLine + fValue.ToString();
                prevOutput = fValue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my .dll code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chapter_1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string output = String.Empty;
        static Class1 var = new Class1();

        public void guideLine()
        {
            one();
        }

        private void one()
        {
            var.output = "Once upon a time, in the realm of Sehrli..." +
                Environment.NewLine + "...there was a... a... what, actually? From which race are you?" +
                Environment.NewLine + "1) Human" +
                Environment.NewLine + "2) Elf" +
                Environment.NewLine + "3) Dwarf" +
                Environment.NewLine + "4) Guardian" +
                Environment.NewLine + "5) Angel" +
                Environment.NewLine + "6) Qanadli" +
                Environment.NewLine + "(Type the number of the option you want to select, or type 'info' and a number to get more info (e.g. info 3))";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried so solve it myself, but I failed (obviously).
Anyone any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variable isn't changing? I don't see any code that attempts to even use the side-effect of calling `guideLine()` in the DLL, but do note that your `one()` method changes the value of the `output` variable in a completely different instance of `Class1` than you are using to call the method. You'd need to access that instance to see the change, or get rid of the `var` field altogether and just use the current instance. I'll also recommend you avoid using "var" as a variable name, as "var" is a reserved word in C#.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a detailed and precise description of what that code does and what you want it to do instead. Please note that for the purposes of an MCVE, it appears you do not need the DLL, as what it looks like you're really having trouble with is just dealing with the dynamically-created object. There's also lots of code here that has clearly has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the lack of information. But I got rid of the var variable as Peter Duniho suggested, and that worked! So thanks!

Why am I using a .dll? I want to make my program in such a way that when I want to add new content, I just need to make a new .dll. But I first wanted to get used to .dll's. That's why this .dll seems a bit pointless.

Thanks for helping me out!